# slicing numpy arrays by combining indices and expression masks

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, slice

I've to analyse a (~20k vertices) 3D quad mesh and therefor need to decompose it into submeshes according to certain criteria.

Given are

- an array of vertices (N 3-tuples of vertex coordinates, to be precise)
- quad faces referencing the sequence number of those vertices
- the reverse map of vertices to the sequential number of the (4) faces they belong to

The basic criteria for the decomposition come in two flavors:

- as sequences of face- or vertex-indices
- or as expressions

Those basic criteria need to be composed to yield the sets I need for my analyses.

It's easy to get an index list from an expression criterion; that's simply

```py
numpy.where(mask)
```

What I don't know is how to efficiently get a mask from a given list of indices; the brute force approach in my SSCCE below (at (A))

```py
boolean_mask_from_selected_face_indices = [
    i in selected_face_indices for i in range(faces.shape[0])
]
```

Works, but looks inefficient.

**Thus I'd like to know a better way to get from index-based "masks" to boolean masking.**

I reduced the SSCCE coords to two real dims and instead of IR² vecs I use complex numbers for representation - that flattens it a little; the topic is unaffected by that simplification.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import numpy as np

# ----------------------mocking the static data ----------------------72

phi = np.pi/4.

# corners of an axis-aligned square in the complex plane
coords = np.array(
    [
        np.complex(np.cos(a), np.sin(a))
        for a in np.arange(phi, 8 * phi, 2 * phi)
    ])

# appending cornes for a square turned left by pi/4 = 45 deg
w = coords[0]
coords = np.append(coords, coords * w)
# print np.round(coords)

# indices for both quads
faces = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)

# generating dummy duplicates
faces = np.append(faces, faces, axis=0)
print faces
# which are to be excluded
apriori_face_mask = [True, True, False, False]

# reverse indexing
vertex_faces = np.append(np.zeros(4, dtype=int), np.ones(4, dtype=int))
# for the duplicates
vertex_faces = np.append(vertex_faces, vertex_faces)

# ---------------------------- runtime -------------------------------72

# selecting vertices by certain criteria
runtime_mask = (np.imag(coords) > (float(1.) - np.finfo(float).eps))

# selecting the corresponding face
selected_face_indices = vertex_faces[np.where(runtime_mask)]

# ################################################################
# (A) this is what I'd like to improve
# ################################################################
boolean_mask_from_selected_face_indices = [
    i in selected_face_indices for i in range(faces.shape[0])
]
# ################################################################

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# (B) combining the two filters
selected_faces = faces[
    np.logical_and(apriori_face_mask,
                   boolean_mask_from_selected_face_indices)
]
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

assert(selected_faces.shape[0] == 1)

try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    res = coords[selected_faces.flat]
    plt.fill(np.real(res), np.imag(res), facecolor="r")
    plt.show()
except ImportError as e:
    print("No matplotlib.pyplot; text result is:")
    print(selected_faces)
```

It may be important to state that for my work, I don't need to re-index faces; for my needs it's good enough  that only the face selection reflects the current working set, carrying along the whole load of vertices doesn't cost me anything.

That has the implication that I also don't want to bother with any re-indexing and the related costs if that can be avoided.

numpy version is 1.9.1
platform is 64bit (Debian jessie amd64)

**EDIT:** 
OK, this

```py
arr = [False for _ in (range(faces.shape[0]))]
for i in selected_face_indices:
    arr[i] = True
boolean_mask_from_selected_face_indices = arr
```

is obviously better, but I would still like to avoid that loop somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a list of indices directly to index your array. So this would work:

```
import numpy as np
indices = [1, 3, 7]
mask = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.bool)
mask[indices] = True
print(mask) # [False  True False  True False False False  True False False]
```

Comment: Sure. You're absolutely right. I knew I missed sth. :) Thx a lot!